# How can I get the AWS Lambda Alias in my Go function?

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I want to run some Lambda alias specific code before my main function starts executing. It currently looks like this

```
func init() {
 // Trying to get Lambda function alias here
}

func main() {
 adapter = chiproxy.New(r)
 lambda.start(lambdaHandler)
}

func lambdaHandler(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
 c, err := adapter.ProxyWithContext(ctx, req)
 return c, err
}
```

`req` in `lambdaHandler` has the info I need but I don't know how to get it in init()?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get the alias before the function has been passed  a request.  lambda automatically provides [a number of environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime) but alias is not one of them.

That's probably because the alias is just a pointer to the version; you could have many aliases pointing to the same version, but the same function runtime could be initialized for all of them.  So it wouldn't make sense to provide any particular alias at initialization time.

> I want to run some Lambda alias specific code before my main function starts executing

But the function's runtime isn't specific to an alias, it's specific to a version.  In fact you could create a new alias after the version had been instantiated, and the same cached runtime could be used.

I think I can see why you might want to have invokers call the same function with different aliases, but I'm not sure it's going to be a low friction path to achieve what you want with aliases.  Consider whether you might instead want to create bunch of *different* functions - which could have the same codebase, and have init choose a proper handler or do other init based on the function *name* instead of its *alias*.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel! The reason I am doing this is to get the environment name through the alias. I did consider setting up different functions but then I use API Gateway to invoke the Lambda and I don't think I can trigger different functions from the various stages in Gateway.